# How to correctly deploy/install scripts?

Tags: shell-script, software-installation, alias, deployment

I've developed several utility scripts that solve specific problems of my team's day-to-day work.

Up to now, what I have done to deploy the script in my co-workers' laptops is as follows:

- Every solution has a `main.sh` script (as well as other scripts and supporting files)
- Create a folder in the user's home folder and put the files there
- Add an alias either to `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`, depending on the Linux distribution, pointing to the `main.sh` script
- Copy autocompletion file to `/etc/bash_completion.d/` (completion file name is the same as the alias plus `.auto` extension).
- Copy man page to `/usr/share/man/man1/` then gzipping it (man file name is the same as the alias plus `.1` extension).

I would like to create an installer but the alias part is tricky.

- Is there a better option that would also allow for automation (installer)?
- Maybe putting a soft link to main.sh file in `/usr/local/bin` instead of creating aliases?
- Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: Using a proper build system like Cmake or autotools, plus packaging code as a binary package is a good start. Of course, it does depend on what you are trying to do. Single scripts don't necessarily need packages.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not terribly difficult to work in an *init* feature into a shell function. For example:

```
fn(){ 
    echo first time called\!
    fn(){ 
        echo not the first time called\!
    }
}
fn; fn; fn
```

...will print...

```
first time called!
not the first time called!
not the first time called!
```

You can also define shell aliases in a function, or source files, or any manner of things - you can do *pretty* much anything with the current shell's state that you can also do at the prompt *except* affect its positional parameters *(though even that can be worked around with `alias`es)*.

So it *could* be a good idea to source your installations as `.fn.name` *(or whatever)* files and then to call them once in the rc file - where the initial call to the function handles all its own setup as necessary and then redefines itself for all calls thereafter.

Or, similar to some shells will do with *autoload*, you can create a one-line function that is defined every time the rc file is read like:

```
printf '%b' '[ -f ~/.fn_name ] &&\n\tfn_name(){ . ~/.fn_name; }\n' >>~/.bash.rc
```

...and within `~/.fn_name`...

```
fn_name(){ : now redefine the function; }
```

...in that way the `fn_name` will use hardly any shell state at all until it is first called, it will not clutter the `.bash.rc` terribly, and can be easily managed.

It might be easier, though, to put all of those types in a single `~/.fn` file and, to source it from the main rc, and then to source each individual from out of it.

Comment: +1 But that would be tricky to automate in an installer, because running the installer more than once would insert the entry several times in the rc file.

Comment: @user1598390 - well, not necessarily. You can do a `grep -q fn_name <~/.fn && ...` test first, or something like - or just do `[ -f ~/.fn_name ] || install` - so long as you set up some rules that you can abide by you can do the tests pretty easily.

Comment: I haven't accepted this answer after so long, because I don't fully understand it. Would you please make it a little more easy ti digest? Perhaps not asumming that I know certain concepts. O perhaps explaining where exactly to copy things.